# ordiplot3d colour by treatment/category

Tags: vegan

I have to make a 3d ordination (NMDS) since there was too much stress with the 3D.

I'm able to make a 3d ordination using oriplot3d, but cannot figure out how to colour the points by a category in my metadata. Also, I'm using Phyloseq.

Does anyone know of a simple solution?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

`ordiplot3d` is in the **vegan3d** package. It has the following documentation (see `?ordiplot3d`):

```
col: Colours of points. Can be a vector, and factors are
      interpreted as their internal numerical codes.
```

You should give the name of the variable (vector) containing the "metadata" as the argument.